# Retrieve and compute prices in MySQL using conditions

Tags: mysql, case

I want to retrieve/compute the price on a given date for different assets, depending on the side of the transaction. Prior to 2000, I have mid quotes, afterwards I have bid and ask or offer quotes, so I would like the price to be the average of these two quotes. More precisely:

```
SELECT date, price,
CASE WHEN side='' THEN 'price_mid'
WHEN side='A' THEN 'price_ask'
WHEN side='B' THEN 'price_bid'
WHEN side='O' THEN 'price_offer'
END as prices 
FROM table
WHERE asset = 'a';
```

How can I then compute the price in a new column, having the price_mid (prior to 2000) and (price_bid+price_ask)/2 or (price_bid+price_offer)/2 afterwards?

E.g.: Let's say I have the following situation:

```
date    price      prices
1         1       price_mid
2        1.1      price_mid
3        0.9      price_bid
3        1.2      price_ask
4        1.3      price_offer
4        1.1      price_bid
```

And I would like to have:

```
date    final_price
 1           1
 2          1.1
 3          1.05
 4          1.2
```

Comment: can you please share schema of your table and expected result?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have edited the question and added them.

Comment: which possibilities are there? which tuples do you want to handle how? If you have price_mid, price_offer and price_ask, what do you want?

Comment: So the final_price=price_mid; otherwise,  final_price=(price_bid+price_ask)/2 or final_price=(price_bid+price_offer)/2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand you need the average for only some dates. Maybe the following does what you want:

```
SELECT date, AVG(price) as AvgValue
FROM prices
WHERE date >= 2
AND prices in ('price_ask','price_offer','price_bid')
GROUP BY date
UNION
SELECT date, price as AvgValue
FROM prices
WHERE date < 2
AND prices = 'price_mid'
GROUP BY date
UNION
SELECT date, price as AvgValue
FROM prices p
WHERE date >= 2
AND prices = 'price_mid'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM prices p2 where p2.date = p.date AND p2.prices in ('price_ask','price_offer','price_bid'))
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY DATE ASC
```

Comment: What do you do if you have price_mid, price_ask & price_bid?

Comment: I updated the query, is this closer to what you want now? I am trying to understand the requirement. For old dates you want only price_mid, correct? And for newer dates, you want to ignore price_mid and calculate the average of everything else that exists?

Comment: @dchar Thank you for your answer. What you stated is correct, but it can be the case that during the same day, I have more prices. After some date,I don't have price_mid anymore, so I want to take the average of bid and ask alone or bid and offer, as some quotes differ. From my understanding, this translates into the fact that in your code, the last union is not necessary, right? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, the last union is to ignore price_mid if it exists. If you are certain that it doesn't, then you can ommit it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
SELECT `date`, AVG(price) AS final_price FROM tbl GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: What do you do if you have price_mid, price_ask & price_bid?

Answer (score 0):

**Tried something, it did not work, nevertheless maybe that helps..**

This is a changed version of the query you already have, but it does not save a kind of state, it only has all the values on the right places.

```
SELECT 
    date,
    CASE WHEN side = '' THEN price
                        ELSE NULL
    END as price_mid,
    CASE WHEN side = 'A' THEN price
                         ELSE NULL
    END as price_ask,
    CASE WHEN side = 'B' THEN price
                         ELSE NULL
    END as price_bid,
    CASE WHEN side = '' THEN price
                        ELSE NULL
    END as price_offer
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
     asset = 'a';
```

What should give you:

```
date    price_mid price_ask price_bid price_offer
1         1       NULL      NULL      NULL
2        1.1      NULL      NULL      NULL      
3       NULL      NULL      0.9       NULL
3       NULL       1.2      NULL      NULL
4       NULL      NULL      NULL      1,4
4       NULL      NULL      1.1       NULL
```

Now on that table you can check with `IS NULL` or take the `SUM()`or the `MAX()` per date, so you can switch through your cases on one line.

Comment: Sorry that I did not reached what I wanted to reach, maybe I finish the answer tomorrow.. But there is a way like that, a way not killing it when you have a three of those values (like the others fail with that)